# How to sent mail by live hosting?

Tags: php, html, email

This is my main html form which i fetch user input and sent it to `contact.php`.

```
 <form action="forms/contact.php" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
            <div class="validate"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <div class="validate"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <div class="loading">Loading</div>
            <div class="error-message"></div>
            <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" name="submit">Send Message</button></div>
        </form>
```

this is my **script to sent mail online by hosting**. but it doesn't work or not showing any error how can i sent mail.

Is there any other way I can sent mails without SMTP(simple mail transfer protocol).

```
 <?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $fromEmail = $_POST['email'];
    $subjectName = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $to = 'satindersinghmatharu786@gmail.com';
    $subject = $subjectName;
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: '.$fromEmail.'<'.$fromEmail.'>' . "\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$fromEmail."\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $message = '<!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport"
                  content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <span class="preheader" style="color: transparent; display: none; height: 0; max-height: 0; max-width: 0; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; mso-hide: all; visibility: hidden; width: 0;">'.$message.'</span>
            <div class="container">
             '.$message.'<br/>
                Regards<br/>
              '.$fromEmail.'
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>';
    $result = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    echo '<script>alert("Email sent successfully !")</script>';
    echo '<script>window.location.href="index.php";</script>';
  }
```

Comment: By adding `@` in front of `mail` you are blocking any errors that might show up. Remove it and test it again.

Comment: For this method you have configure your server for mailing.

Comment: @vaku i used free hosting server how can i configure it. I used 000webhost server